# Do we need Write-Output at all?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Let's see short PS-snippets:

```
Write-Output @(1,2,3)
Write-Output @(1,2,3).Count
Get-Process|Write-Output
Write-Output (Get-Process)
$p=7890;Write-Output "Var. is $p"
Write-Output "ABCD78".Length

Function Get-StoppedService {

Param([string]$Computername = $env:computername)

$s = Get-Service -ComputerName $Computername
$stopped = $s | where {$_.Status -eq 'Stopped'}
Write-Output $Stopped
}
Get-StoppedService
```

In all snippets above I can just wipe out string **Write-Output** (with trailing space, if any) and will have exactly the same functionality.
The question is: do you know example where we CAN'T throw off Write-Output? Of course, if you interesting in Write-Output's parameter *-NoEnumerate* you can't eliminate cmdlet itself, so let's suppose we don't want/need *-NoEnumerate*. In this case - do you have example?

Comment: You may redefine `Write-Output`. I did not see much applications of this, but this is a possibility to keep in mind.

Comment: PetSerAl, you just "trick" PS-engine. You try to create array of strings and print it's elements. According PowerShell Language Specification(ver. 3.0) only two variants are  STRICTLY syntactical valid: write "a","b","c","d","e" or write 'a','b','c','d','e'. In both cases you can wipe out "write" and get what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Well MSDN itself has the the following [statement](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849921.aspx)

> This cmdlet is typically used in scripts to display strings and other
>   objects on the console. However, **because the default behavior is to
>   display the objects at the end of a pipeline, it is generally not
>   necessary to use the cmdlet.** For example, get-process | write-output
>   is equivalent to get-process.

One case in which it might be useful is when you build a pipeline with unknown stages, i.e. stages which are given to you via parameters etc. and the user could give you any cmdlet for the stage e.g. `Tee-Object`. If the user don't want anything special to happen, he could simply pass `Write-Output` as a kind of "pass-through" stage (of course you could easily implement that yourself as well)

Answer (score 1):

As is often the case, [PetSerAl's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) pithy examples (by way of a comment on the question, in this case) lead to epiphanies:

**While generally *not* needed** (see [DAXaholic's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38271641/45375); you don't even need `Write-Output` for `-NoEnumerate`, because that can be emulated with the unary array-construction operator, `,`), **`Write-Output` can provide *syntactic sugar***:

`(Write-Output a b c d e | Measure-Object).Count` yields `5`, which demonstrates that `Write-Output` **accepts an arbitrary number of individual arguments**, which are sent through the pipeline / to the screen one by one.

As such, `Write-Output` can simplify sending a collection of items to the output stream, by not *requiring* them to be quoted, because, as a cmdlet, `Write-Output`'s parameters are parsed in [*argument* mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx):

Thus, instead of a "noisy" array literal such as the following (with its need for quoting the elements and separating them with `,`):

```
"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"
```

you can simply write (albeit at the expense of performance):

```
Write-Output a b c d e
```